# Analysing YouTube comments using Python -- parameter has disabled comments

Tags: python, youtube, nlp

I'm trying to get into text analysis using YouTube comments. I've been using the code from the following website to scrape YouTube:

https://www.pingshiuanchua.com/blog/post/using-youtube-api-to-analyse-youtube-comments-on-python

The script starts working, but there is a section of the code that generates an error if comments have been disabled, and I can't find a way to check to see if comments are disabled or if comments exist, and to just skip that video if there are no comments to scrape, and continue on to the next video.

The code chunk in question creating the error is:

```
# =============================================================================
# Get Comments of Top Videos
# =============================================================================

video_id_pop = []
channel_pop = []
video_title_pop = []
video_desc_pop = []
comments_pop = []
comment_id_pop = []
reply_count_pop = []
like_count_pop = []

from tqdm import tqdm

for i, video in enumerate(tqdm(video_id, ncols = 100)):
    response = service.commentThreads().list(
                    part = 'snippet',
                    videoId = video,
                    maxResults = 100, # Only take top 100 comments...
                    order = 'relevance', #... ranked on relevance
                    textFormat = 'plainText',
                    ).execute()
    
    comments_temp = []
    comment_id_temp = []
    reply_count_temp = []
    like_count_temp = []
    for item in response['items']:
        comments_temp.append(item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textDisplay'])
        comment_id_temp.append(item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['id'])
        reply_count_temp.append(item['snippet']['totalReplyCount'])
        like_count_temp.append(item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['likeCount'])
    comments_pop.extend(comments_temp)
    comment_id_pop.extend(comment_id_temp)
    reply_count_pop.extend(reply_count_temp)
    like_count_pop.extend(like_count_temp)
    
    video_id_pop.extend([video_id[i]]*len(comments_temp))
    channel_pop.extend([channel[i]]*len(comments_temp))
    video_title_pop.extend([video_title[i]]*len(comments_temp))
    video_desc_pop.extend([video_desc[i]]*len(comments_temp))
    
query_pop = [query] * len(video_id_pop)
```

Edited to add:

The person who created the code left a message to fix the error saying:

"You can wrap the query part of the code in a try...except statement, where if the try statement (the query part) failed, you can push an except of blank response or "error" string into the list."

I have NFI how to carry this out if it makes sense to anyone else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: this is not necessarily "good" coding style, but it's the sort of thing I would do if I ran into this problem when I was writing a script for my own short-term, personal use.

Python (and many other languages) have a way to catch exceptions and handle them without crashing. Used properly, this can be a very nice way to handle bad data.

https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/errors.html is a good overview of exceptions. In general, the format they take is something like

```
try:
    code_that_can_error()
except ExceptionThatWIllBeThrown as ex:
    handle_exception()
    print(ex) # ex is an object that has information about what went wrong
finally:
    clean_up()
```

(Finally is particularly useful if you have something you need to call close on, like a file. If the exception is thrown, you might not close it, but a finally is guaranteed to get called, even if an exception is thrown.)

In your case, all we need is to ignore the error and move on to the next video.

```
for i, video in enumerate(tqdm(video_id, ncols = 100)):
    try:
        response = service.commentThreads().list(
                        part = 'snippet',
                        videoId = video,
                        maxResults = 100, # Only take top 100 comments...
                        order = 'relevance', #... ranked on relevance
                        textFormat = 'plainText',
                        ).execute()
    
        comments_temp = []
        [...]
        video_desc_pop.extend([video_desc[i]]*len(comments_temp))
    except:
        # Something threw an error. Skip that video and move on
        print(f"{video} has comments disabled, or something else went wrong")

query_pop = [query] * len(video_id_pop)
```